# Android / PHP - Struggling to Post Data

Tags: php, android

I'm struggling to find out what the problem is. The exact same code works in another project. It works in the current project if I point it to the URL in the previous project - but on a new URL it simply won't post NameValuePairs.

This is what I'm using to retrieve the string:

```
public static String getJSON(String url, List<BasicNameValuePair> params, int timeout) {

    String response = "";
    try {

        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);

        URL uri = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();

        request.setUseCaches(false);
        request.setDoOutput(true);
        request.setDoInput(true);

        request.setRequestMethod("POST");
        OutputStream post = request.getOutputStream();
        entity.writeTo(post);
        post.flush();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine = "";
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response += inputLine;
            // res = response;
        }
        post.close();
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Your app", "error", e);
    }

    return response;

}
```

This is my PHP file:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Type'])){
    print_r($_POST);
}else {
    echo "No post received";
}

?>
```

Here is my request:

```
            List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Type", "20"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("version", "1.3"));

            String stringArrayElement = "\n";
            String result = Config.getJSON(Config.MyUrl + "test4.php", nameValuePair, 1000);
            JSONObject JSON_DATA;

            // Making HTTP Request

            try {
                JSON_DATA = new JSONObject(result);

                Downloaded_menu_array = JSON_DATA.getJSONArray("Menu");

            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

It always hits "No post received" in my PHP file. Is there anything that jumps out with the code or am I missing something else?

Comment: In the PHP, can you log `$_REQUEST` to show what request did come in?

Comment: I tried that, I just get a blank post when I return print_r(); The code is copy and pasted from another of my projects - only difference is URL. Could I be missing something with restrictions posting via external sources? I checked over max post size in the ini file but it runs the same ini as the other URL. Same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite embarrassing.

Turns out it was the domain - it had a redirect on redirecting http://www.domain.com to http://domain.com meaning the url in my Config.MyUrl was incorrect.

It threw me as it was still hitting the file - I can only guess that it hit the file before it redirected and finished processing after it redirected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem relies in how you are calling your php file (in this case, `getJSON`) which will perform a `GET` request, thats why your `$_POST` array is empty. For debugging purposes, in your php script, try this:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

And check if you get anything. I'm pretty sure that the following line:

```
String result = Config.getJSON(Config.MyUrl + "test4.php", nameValuePair, 1000);
```

Is the root cause of your empty response. You should try to either perform a POST request to your script, or retrieve your data in the script via the `$_GET` method.

Comment: getJSON is the name of my string void: public static String getJSON(String url, List<BasicNameValuePair> params, int timeout) within that file I specify that it is a POST request  request.setRequestMethod("POST");

Comment: Than i'm afraid that you should always provide all relevant code to your questions in order to avoid this kind of confusions. a method called getJSON is telling (at least me) that you are performing a get method call.

Comment: The method (which I posted above) is called getJSON because I am getting JSON from an URL.

Comment: My bad, I did not realize you've posted the code before. I'm sorry.